# Using Class method to add a Class variable

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

The following code adds two Pretty Tables to `MyTableClass`. The tables are initiated in the class constructor. I would like to create two Class methods `addTable` and `addTableRow` for adding additional tables and data rows by specifying a `newTable` name. What is the syntax I need to do this? I wrote some code in Class methods as place holder.

```
from prettytable import *

class MyTableClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.table1 =PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Score Test 1"])
        self.table2=PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Score Test 2"])

    def addTable (self, newTable, **kwargs):
        #What is the syntax to make NewTable a Class variable of MyTableClass?
        self.newTable = PrettyTable(kwargs.values())

    def addTableRow(self, newTable, **kwargs):
        #What is the syntax to use newTable to add data to added table?
        self.newTable.add_row(kwargs.values())


def main():
    m = MyTableClass()
    m.table1.add_row(["Kenny", 86])
    m.table1.add_row(["Jackson", 72])
    m.table1.add_row(["Charlie", 100])
    m.table2.add_row(["Kenny", 95])
    m.table2.add_row(['Jackson', 85])
    m.table2.add_row(["Charlie", 99])


print (m.table1)
print (m.table2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. None of these methods are classmethods, and none of the attributes are class-level ones. And what's wrong with the syntax you have?

Comment: I believe the indentation of `print( m.table1)` is wrong, because that would raise an error. They should probably be indented together with `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#setattr) function to set the attribute:

```
def addTable (self, newTable, **kwargs):
    setattr(self, newTable, PrettyTable(kwargs.values()))
```

And you can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr) to obtain the attribute from its name:

```
def addTableRow(self, newTable, **kwargs):
    getattr(self, newTable).add_row(kwargs.values())
```

However it would be simpler to simply use a dictionary of the tables:

```
class MyTableClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tables = {
            'table1': PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Score Test 1"]),
            'table2': PrettyTable(["Student Name", "Score Test 2"]),
        }

    def addTable (self, newTable, **kwargs):
        self.tables[newTable] = PrettyTable(kwargs.values())

    def addTableRow(self, newTable, **kwargs):
        self.tables[newTable].add_row(kwargs.values())
```

If you want to be able to access a given table via attribute, like `self.table1` in your examples, just define [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) as:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return self.tables[name]
```

Comment: `setattr` and 'getattr` do exactly what I was looking for. The dictionary approach looks very clean. I will experiment with it.